# mongoose async await, unable to capture connection state

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async-await

I'm trying to capture the connection success state for mongoose/mongodb.
The idea is simply that, when I start the app, if the connection fails, I need an alert recorded.
I can't figure out why, once I connect - or once the connection fails - the function does not return what I tell it to return.

```
import { DBURL } from '../parameters/environment';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const chalk = require('chalk');

const connected = chalk.bold.cyan;
const error = chalk.bold.yellow;

const connectMe = async () => {
  await mongoose.connect(DBURL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => {
      console.log(connected('DB connection successful'));
      return 'Success';
    })
    .catch((reason) => {
      console.log(error('Unable to connect to the mongodb instance. Error: '), reason);
      return 'FAIL';
    });
  return 'Why am I returning this????';
};

module.exports = connectMe;
```

I simply call it and try to display the result. 
But regardless of the DB state, the return statement in .then or .catch is ignored
Server.js:

```
const connectMe = require('./db-actions/db-connect');

const myResult = connectMe();
myResult.then(x => console.log(x));
```

If mongodb is up, I get this:

> DB connection successful
>   Why am I returning this????

If mongodb is down, I get this:

> Unable to connect to the mongodb instance. Error:  MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:30000
>   Why am I returning this????

Console.log works, but the return does not. 
Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why it seems return is not working:**
You are combining both `async/await` and `.then/.catch`, you should choose one of the two. Also, the `return` keyword is not properly placed within `connectMe` the function.

**The fix:**
Since, you are expecting the `connectMe` function to return a promise so you can attach a `.then` like this:

```
myResult.then(x => console.log(x));
```

You can just go with a `.then/.catch` in the `connectMe` function and the `return` statement should be on `mongoose.connect`, that's the promise the outside world(i.e outside the function) needs to interact with. Code:

```
const connectMe = () => {
  return mongoose.connect(DBURL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => {
      console.log(connected('DB connection successful'));
      return 'Success';
    })
    .catch ((reason) =>  {
      console.log(error('Unable to connect to the mongodb instance. Error: '), reason);
      return 'FAIL';
    })
};
```